# different cygwin results on 2 different machines : "cannot execute binary file"

Tags: bash, cygwin

I compile .c file and generate .exe file in cygwin on 2 different machines: 
One windows 8 64-bit and another windows 7 64-bit.

Every thing is similar: cygwin, compilation command: `gcc -std=gnu99 -o .....`, PATH in environment variable, and etc. But .exe file executes on win7 machine but on win8 machine, I get this error:

```
cannot execute binary file: Exec format error.
```

I run `file ./fileName` and the results are:

For win7:

```
PE32+ executable (console) x86-64, for MS Windows
```

For win8:

```
ELF 64-bit LSB executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, for GNU/Linux 2.6.24, BuildID ......, not stripped
```

Comment: That win8 output seems to indicate that you didn't build a Windows executable. You are sure the compilation command is the same? And the compiler (and compiler version) and compiler toolchains are the same?

Answer (score 0):

You're probably using 32-bit cygwin on both machine, but on windows 8 it compiling to a 64-bit executable.  Simple tell `gcc` to generate 32-bit code with the `-m32` flag, something like:

```
gcc -std=gnu99 -m32 -o .....
```